# AG Replica on anther WSFC

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering

Is it possible that an AG spans two different WSFC failover clusters, i.e. one of the nodes is part of another WSFC failover cluster.

So is it possible that one of the replicas is hosted on a node that is not part of the cluster?
In other words can one replica be configured as a read-scale replica not part of the cluster (but perhaps part of another cluster).

SQL Server versions are 2019.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible that an AG spans two different WSFC failover clusters, i.e. one of the nodes is part of another WSFC failover cluster.

Yes, you'll need to create a distributed AG.

> So is it possible that one of the replicas is hosted on a node that is not part of the cluster?

All replicas need to be in the same cluster, hence why you'll need to create a distributed AG.

> In other words can one replica be configured as a read-scale replica not part of the cluster (but perhaps part of another cluster).

No, the configuration is at the AG level, not the replica level. They are all  WSFC/External/None, you can't mix and match at the replica level.